# Executing an update/delete query

Tags: java, spring-security, grails, groovy

Estoy migrando de grails 2.0.4 a 4.0.4 y en el método delete no funciona de manera adecuada me manda el siguiente error:

> Class javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException Message null
> Caused by Executing an update/delete query

Ya utilice las cabeceras para que lo reconociera como un transaction pero no funciona, la idea es eliminar el valor de la tabla intermedia de donde pertenece el usuario y su rol

```
package com.djamware
import grails.validation.ValidationException
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.*
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured

class UserController {

UserService userService

static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]
@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER'])
def index(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    respond userService.list(params), model:[userCount: userService.count()]
}
@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER'])
def show(Long id) {
    respond userService.get(id)
}
@Secured('ROLE_ADMIN')
def create() {
    respond new User(params)
}
@Secured('ROLE_ADMIN')
def save(User user) {
    if (user == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    try {
        userService.save(user)
    } catch (ValidationException e) {
        respond user.errors, view:'create'
        return
    }

    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), user.id])
            redirect user
        }
        '*' { respond user, [status: CREATED] }
    }
}
@Secured('ROLE_ADMIN')
def edit(Long id) {
    respond userService.get(id)
}
@Secured('ROLE_ADMIN')
def update(User user) {
    if (user == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    try {
        userService.save(user)
    } catch (ValidationException e) {
        respond user.errors, view:'edit'
        return
    }

    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), user.id])
            redirect user
        }
        '*'{ respond user, [status: OK] }
    }
}
@Secured('ROLE_ADMIN')
def delete(Long id) {
    if (id == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    //userService.delete(id)

    def userInstance = User.get(id)

    def userID = User.executeQuery("select id from User where username = '" + userInstance + "'")

    def delete=  UserRole.executeUpdate("delete from UserRole where userId =2")



    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), id])
            redirect action:"index", method:"GET"
        }
        '*'{ render status: NO_CONTENT }
    }
}

protected void notFound() {
    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), params.id])
            redirect action: "index", method: "GET"
        }
        '*'{ render status: NOT_FOUND }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EL PROBLEMA ESTABA EN QUE AL MOMENTO DE MAPEAR EL DOMINIO GRAILS CREA LAS RELACIONES CON LLAVES FORANEAS PERO NO CREA LA SENTENCIA ON DELETE CASCADE, ES POR ELLO QUE CUANDO SE QUERIA ELIMINAR EL USUARIO JUNTO CON SU USERROLE, NO SE LO PERMITIA Y MANDABA EL ERROR, TERMINE METIENDO LA TABLA INTERMEDIA DE FORMA MANUAL Y CUANDO ELIMINE TODO FUNCIONO DE MANERA CORRECTA, EL CÓDIGO QUEDA COMO GRAILS 4.0.4 TE LO CREA

package com.app.admin.domain.security

import grails.validation.ValidationException

import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.*

import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured

class UserController {

```
UserService userService

static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]
@Secured('ROLE_ADMIN')
def index(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    respond userService.list(params), model:[userCount: userService.count()]
}
@Secured('ROLE_ADMIN')
def show(Long id) {
    respond userService.get(id)
}
@Secured('ROLE_ADMIN')
def create() {
    respond new User(params)
}
@Secured('ROLE_ADMIN')
def save(User user) {
    if (user == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    try {
        userService.save(user)
    } catch (ValidationException e) {
        respond user.errors, view:'create'
        return
    }

    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), user.id])
            redirect user
        }
        '*' { respond user, [status: CREATED] }
    }
}
@Secured('ROLE_ADMIN')
def edit(Long id) {
    respond userService.get(id)
}
@Secured('ROLE_ADMIN')
def update(User user) {
    if (user == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    try {
        userService.save(user)
    } catch (ValidationException e) {
        respond user.errors, view:'edit'
        return
    }

    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), user.id])
            redirect user
        }
        '*'{ respond user, [status: OK] }
    }
}
@Secured('ROLE_ADMIN')
def delete(Long id) {
    if (id == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }
    userService.delete(id)

    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), id])
            redirect action:"index", method:"GET"
        }
        '*'{ render status: NO_CONTENT }
    }
}

protected void notFound() {
    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), params.id])
            redirect action: "index", method: "GET"
        }
        '*'{ render status: NOT_FOUND }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: No redactes en mayúsculas sostenidas por favor, pareciera que gritas